# Synonyms of the loanword "cum"

Tags: synonyms

Is there any other word to express A-cum-B instead of using "cum"? I don't want to use "cum" as it may cause unwanted laughingstock.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here.  Can you explain in what way you're linking A and B? More context will allow for a better answer here.

Comment: A union B maybe? I'm not sure of your context though, so I can't be of much help there. Please elaborate the question with context so you get better tailored answers.

Comment: For example, HR manager-cum-General manager

Answer (score 2):

With the unfortunate modern connotation, it may be better just to omit the word. Instead of using *studio-cum-office*, just use *studio-office*. It will be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *cum* in this sense is "combined" or "with" (from the Latin for "with").

For example a workshop-cum-garage.

Some other ways of expressing that could be:

- A combined workshop and garage
- A combined workshop/garage (you would pronounce this "a workshop slash garage")
- A combination workshop/garage
- A workshop/garage
- A workshop that doubles as a garage

etc