# Grammatical? omission-cum, action-sans

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

I came across this on Quora, but no answer there. I know [*cum* in this sense is "combined" or "with" (from the Latin for "with")](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/354402). [sans](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480437) is French word for ‘without’ in English.
[*Decina* is a New York law case](https://www.lexisnexis.com/community/casebrief/p/casebrief-people-v-decina), but I don't know law or philosophy.

How's bold sentence grammatical? Authors are professors and look very educated! I don't think they are bad grammar. [Michael S. Moore](https://law.illinois.edu/faculty-research/faculty-profiles/michael-s-moore/)

> JD, SJD Harvard University
> AB University of Oregon

[Heidi Hurd](https://law.illinois.edu/faculty-research/faculty-profiles/heidi-hurd/)

> JD, PhD University of Southern California
> MA Dalhousie University
> M.E.M. School of Forestry and Environmental Studies, Yale University
> BA Queen’s University

*Punishing the Awkward, the Stupid, the Weak,
and the Selfish: The Culpability of Negligence* Crim Law and Philos (2011) 5:147–198. [DOI 10.1007/s11572-011-9114-0](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11572-011-9114-0).

> The argument for liability for inadvertent harm causing stemming from the existence of
> these two kinds of precautionary acts is a *Decina*-like argument, albeit based on earlier
> *omissions* that fail to prevent harms rather than on earlier *actions* that positively cause
> harms. The argument is that culpability in such cases is premised on the chosen omission to
> take precautions against the harmful effects of flaws the actor knew she possessed. [1] The
> earlier omission-**cum** awareness replaces the later action-**sans** awareness as the theory of
> liability in such cases.

I try replace "cum" and "sans" with English.

> [2] The
> earlier omission-**WITH** awareness replaces the later action-**WITHOUT** awareness as the theory of
> liability in such cases.

2 is not grammatical. omission-**WITH** and action-**WITHOUT** just weird!

Comment: They're just being snobby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latin terms often incorporate legal concepts and Latin phrases or phrases that include Latin are often set phrases with a specialist meaning.

Based on what knowledge I have of English law, rather than American, "omission-cum" and "action-sans" are noun phrases used attributively describing forms of negligent action.

*(I base this on an American legal concept "Simul cum" (Latin) (See the entry The Free Dictionary) https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Simul+cum*

> *3. When a party sued with another pleads separately, the plea is generally entitled in the name of the person pleading, adding "sued with___," naming the other party. When this occurred, it was, in the old phraseology, called pleading with a simul cum.)*

"Omission-cum" can be understood as "including an omission" and "action sans" can be understood as excluding an action.

The troublesome word is "awareness" - in this context it seems to mean "what was in the person’s mind at the time” (The person was or should have been aware of something.)

omission-cum awareness = the state of mind that knew that failing to do something would cause harm.

Action-sans awareness = the state of mind of doing something that he failed to realise would cause harm.